# SWAP - Ramdisk file make system update crash

Tags: swap

Kubuntu 22.04 LTE
I have 16 GB primary memory on this i7 laptop and 1 TB SSD, I want to add temporary files such as swap, cache etc. as much as possible on the primary memory to save on the number of write cycles on my SSD memory and speed up my old computer a bit.
I tried this, it worked fine until a system update came and I had to remove it. Is there better coding?
See below the coding I did with help from AI:

1. `sudo mkdir /mnt/ramdisk`
2. `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=4G tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`
3. Create the ramdisk file:
   `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
4. `tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`
   `tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0 /mnt/ramdisk/swapfile none swap sw 0 0`
   `tmpfs /var/cache tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0`
5. Rebooted, and it works until system update came and then I got the error report that the system could not be updated. Probably the swap area was too small.
6. Is there a better solution?
7. Can it be included in UBUNTU update

Comment: So... swap is used when you're running out of RAM. And you decided to use RAM for swap ... This is like that "yo dawg" meme: yo dawg, I heard you liked RAM, so I put swap in RAM! Why even bother with swap then? Just don't add swap at all, and you'll use your RAM directly!

Comment: TNX, that's logical! I didn't know and AI didn't know.